# Convert RS232 signal to I2C/CAN/MAVLink signal

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, i2c, can, rs232

I have an airspeed sensor that outputs a RS232 signal: https://www.aeroprobe.com/micro-air-data-system/. I want to connect this sensor to the Pixhawk in order to use the data for my controller implementation. As far as I know, the Pixhawk has I2C, CAN and MAVLink ports. Can I somehow convert the RS232 signal from the sensor to a signal that's compatible with the Pixhawk ?

Comment: This (https://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/common-pixhawk-overview.html) says the Pixhawk has a couple of 5 volt serial ports.  So, can you use them?  Maybe you'll just need voltage-level translation?  For those of us not familiar with your components, please provide part number details, and links.

Answer (score 0):

Search: https://www.google.com/search?q=rs232+to+can+bus+converter

1st result: [https://www.amazon.com/Taidacent-Performance-Stability-Converter-Adapter/dp/B083QH2N7V?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083QH2N7V)

Taidacent High Performance High Stability Serial to CAN Module Serial to CAN Converter RS485 Can Bus Adapter Uart Can Converter RS232 to Can Bus Converter (with Power Adapter 12V1A)

Comment: There are (were?) board-level transceivers as well.  If I recall correctly, SPI to RS232 was more common.  Maxim (now Analog Devices) chips?  Can't seem to find them now on AD's site.

Comment: "RS232 to CAN for $35" sounds like a scam, there's no sensible way that will work given how different the data link layer frames are. You'll need a programmable gateway or similar.